# Is there a way to reduce the number of rows in mysql depending on a common column?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update these rows based on the location, to add quantities and put in a single row with the same location
[image]

Comment: I want to delete all the rows and just leave two rows one for loc1 and another for loc2.

Comment: `delete from table where id in (81,82,84)`

Comment: Are you sure you want to update the table? If so, you need to show what you want the data to look like after the update operation. Perhaps you simply want to select a `SUM(quantity)` grouped by `location`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two queries needed.

```sql
UPDATE test t1
JOIN ( SELECT MIN(id) id,
              SUM(quantity) quantity,
              location                                   /* (1) */
              FROM test
              GROUP BY location ) t2 USING (location)    /* (1) */
SET t1.quantity = CASE WHEN t1.id = t2.id
                       THEN t2.quantity
                       ELSE 0
                       END;

DELETE FROM test WHERE !quantity;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ffcfa55689e39c95d32369aab74b416)

**(1)** - use all columns which identifies a group to be summarized (for example, for shown data it can be `order_id, location` columns pair).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I want it